# how can I change all price view in drupal commerce

Tags: entities, commerce

I want to change default drupal view of price in all of my field,
as a example I want to remove '00' and add my custom postfix to it,

I found `hook_commerce_price_field_formatter_prepare_view` but when I implement it in my module it not called,really I am not sure this hook is suitable and ca  achieve my need??

I just want the all price fields changes to my desire only  in front-end view (only in view, because my payment method is according to main currency)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using the Commerce Currency API

Implement [`hook_commerce_currency_info_alter`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!commerce!commerce.api.php/function/hook_commerce_currency_info_alter/7) and add your own [`commerce_currency_format`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!commerce!commerce.module/function/commerce_currency_format/7) handler

e.g:

```
/**
 * hook_commerce_currency_info_alter
 * 
 * Add custom currency format to selected currencies
 */
function MY_MODULE_commerce_currency_info_alter(&$currencies){
  $currencies['IRR']['format_callback'] = 'MY_MODULE_commerce_currency_format';
}

/**
 * Currency format callback
 *
 * Remove decimal places from output
 * while keeping commerce_amount_to_decimal formatting the same
 *
 * See: commerce_currency_format
 */
function MY_MODULE_commerce_currency_format($amount, $currency, $object = NULL, $convert = TRUE) {

  // Format the price as a number.
  // In our case, we remove decimal places
  $price = number_format(commerce_currency_round(abs($amount), $currency), 0, $currency['decimal_separator'], $currency['thousands_separator']);

  // Establish the replacement values to format this price for its currency.
  $replacements = array(
    '@code_before' => $currency['code_placement'] == 'before' ? $currency['code'] : '',
    '@symbol_before' => $currency['symbol_placement'] == 'before' ? $currency['symbol'] : '',
    '@price' => $price,
    '@symbol_after' => $currency['symbol_placement'] == 'after' ? $currency['symbol'] : '',
    '@code_after' => $currency['code_placement'] == 'after' ? $currency['code'] : '',
    '@negative' => $amount < 0 ? '-' : '',
    '@symbol_spacer' => $currency['symbol_spacer'],
    '@code_spacer' => $currency['code_spacer'],
  );

  return trim(t('@code_before@code_spacer@negative@symbol_before@price@symbol_spacer@symbol_after@code_spacer@code_after', $replacements));
}
```

Comment: is this work only in view ?

Comment: our country payment system is with raw price(more zeros), I want to remove some "0" in view, just in view but in payment main value used (with more "0"), It this suitable or it change every where?

Comment: It will work across the site, wherever, the price is displayed.

Comment: only in display or in back-end operation?

Comment: Both the front-end and back-end display will use the new format callback. Note: the raw price value is still stored in the database, the format callback is only used for display.

Comment: tnx for your attention, I will test it,

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonning to complete what David Thomas wrote.
1/ Create a custom module with the code. Replace My_Module by the name of your module.

```
/**
 * hook_commerce_currency_info_alter
 * 
 * Add custom currency format to selected currencies
 */
function MY_MODULE_commerce_currency_info_alter(&$currencies){
  $currencies['IRR']['format_callback'] = 'MY_MODULE_commerce_currency_format';
}

/**
 * Currency format callback
 *
 * Remove decimal places from output
 * while keeping commerce_amount_to_decimal formatting the same
 *
 * See: commerce_currency_format
 */
function MY_MODULE_commerce_currency_format($amount, $currency, $object = NULL, $convert = TRUE) {

  // Format the price as a number.
  // In our case, we remove decimal places
  $price = number_format(commerce_currency_round(abs($amount), $currency), 0, $currency['decimal_separator'], $currency['thousands_separator']);

  // Establish the replacement values to format this price for its currency.
  $replacements = array(
    '@code_before' => $currency['code_placement'] == 'before' ? $currency['code'] : '',
    '@symbol_before' => $currency['symbol_placement'] == 'before' ? $currency['symbol'] : '',
    '@price' => $price,
    '@symbol_after' => $currency['symbol_placement'] == 'after' ? $currency['symbol'] : '',
    '@code_after' => $currency['code_placement'] == 'after' ? $currency['code'] : '',
    '@negative' => $amount  $currency['symbol_spacer'],
    '@code_spacer' => $currency['code_spacer'],
  );

  return trim(t('@code_before@code_spacer@negative@symbol_before@price@symbol_spacer@symbol_after@code_spacer@code_after', $replacements));
}
```

2/ Go to **Custom Currency Setting** (admin/commerce/config/currency/custom-settings) and setup the field Format Callback with: My_Module_ommerce_currency_format

At this point your node will display what you asked, but not your views (or your fields).

3/ To use this setting into your views display, you have to display the node inside your views. If you display a field it won't work. **Views > Show: Content**

Cheers